# Python - Find number of characters that are found in both string1 and string2

Tags: python

I'm trying to find the number of characters in the first string that are also found in the second string. This is what I have so far:

```
def main():
    text1 = raw_input("Enter word 1: ")
    text2 = raw_input("Enter word 2: ")

    print("The number of characters that occur in both", text1, "and", text2, "is", count)

def count(text1, text2):
    char = 0
    for i in text1:
        for j in text2:
            if i == j:
                char += 1

    return char

main()
```

I'm having trouble at def count(). I'm not sure how I can count how many letters occur in text1 and text2 that won't be repeated. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: So you want to find the number of unique characters that appear in both, without duplicates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is, you are not invoking the `count` function, but printing the `count` function object. It should have been

```
print("The number of....", text2, "is", count(text1, text2))
```

Also, you need to increment the counter, if the letter is found in the second string and then you can skip to the next character in the first string. So, you can break out of the loop, like this

```
for i in text1:
    for j in text2:
        if i == j:
            char += 1
            break
```

Since we consider only the first occurrence of `i` in `text2`, we can check if it exists in `text2`, like this

```
for i in text1:
    if i in text2:
        char += 1
```

But remember, it will not consider the duplicates in the original string. For example, `aaa` and `a` will result in count `3`.

Comment: Don't forget the function arguments.

Comment: Ahh, I was missing the `break` and invoking count()! It works now :) thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

Use [set.intersection](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html):

```
(set(text1).intersection(item2))

In [22]: len(set("bana").intersection("banana"))
Out[22]: 3
```

*intersection() will accept any iterable as an argument.*

```
def count(text1, text2):
    return len(set(text1).intersection(text2))
In [24]: count("foo","foobar")
Out[24]: 2
```

If you want duplicates:

```
def count(text1, text2):
    s = set(text2)
    return len([x for x in text1 if  x in s])
In [29]: count("foo","foobar")
Out[29]: 3

In [30]: count("bana","banana")
Out[30]: 4
```

Comment: I am nit-picking here, `find the number of characters in the first string that are also found in the second string`, technically the answer shouldn't be 4? ;-)

Comment: @thefourtheye that's if the OP wants duplicates, which has not been made clear.

Comment: @thefourtheye I suppose it depends how you interpret the question but either way an introduction to sets a will do no harm at all.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a great time to use a `set`, which automatically eliminates duplicates and allows instant lookup.

```
def count(text1, text2):
  numchars = 0
  text1 = set(list(text1))
  text2 = set(list(text2))
  for char in text1:
    if char in text2:
      numchars += 1

  return numchars
```

By converting a string to a list, then to a set, you'll eliminate all duplicate characters in each string (only in the function, though, the strings are fine). You can then check each character in the first set to see if it's in the second set, which is a fixed-time check.

Another note: if you don't want to count uppercase `A` and lowercase `a` as two different characters, use `text1 = set(list(text1.lower()))` instead.

Additionally, you are not invoking the function correctly. You should use `count(text1,text2)` instead of just `count`. Though if you're going to print it out, you need to use `str(count(text1,text2))`, because the `count()` function returns an integer and you can't just concatenate that with a string.

Comment: I'm getting this error: ('The number of characters that occur in both', 'anna', 'and', 'banana', 'is', <function count at 0x02B98570>)

Comment: @annabananana7 Whoops, I was overloading one of the variables. Also you need to use `count()` instead of `count`.

Comment: I'm now getting a type error: TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

Comment: @annabananana7 ah yea, that will happen. `count()` returns an `int` and you need to convert it to a string. Call the function with `str(count(text1,text2))`.

Comment: actually, someone used my code and added a `break` which made it work haha so simple and i couldn't figure it out. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by intersecting the strings (getting the unique characters in 2 strings) and taking the length of the result. Something like this:

```
def strIntersection(s1, s2):
   out = ""
   for c in s1:
     if c in s2 and not c in out:
       out += c
   return out



>>> strIntersection('asdfasdfasfd' , 'qazwsxedc')
'asd'
```

and

```
len(strIntersection('asdfasdfasfd' , 'qazwsxedc'))
3
```

could be your count function.

(Also, you need to call count(text1, text2) and not just conut in your print statement, otherwise it won't call the function)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but if you need to add up the total number of letters in text1 and text2, and print the result, that's very easy to do. Please see below:

```
text1 = raw_input("Enter word 1: ")
text2 = raw_input("Enter word 2: ")

x = len(text1) + len(text2)

print "The number of characters that occur in both text1 and text2 is " + str(x)
```